# функция fread читает лишнее. Как исправить это?

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    typedef struct list
    {
        char sur[128];
        int  ball;
        int  mark;
    }list;
    int addstud(char *std,list *stud);
    int viewinfo(char *std,list *stud);

    int main()
    {
     list stud;
     int n=0,i=0,menu;
     char std[] = "stud.txt";
     FILE *fl;

     while (1)
     {
        printf("1)Add new student\n2)Show list of students\n3)Change info about student\n4)Delete student\n5)Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&menu);
        switch (menu)
        {
     case 1:
            addstud(std,&stud);
           // printf("lol:%d",n);
            n++;
            break;
     case 2:
            viewinfo(std,&stud);
            break;
     case 5:

            return 0;
     default:
            printf("Eror, please try again!\n");
            //system("cls");
        }

     }
    }

    int addstud(char *std,list *stud)
{
    FILE *fl;
    fl  = fopen(std, "a");
    if (fl == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter surname student: ");
    scanf("%s",stud->sur);
    fprintf(fl,"%-9s",stud->sur);
    printf("Enter scores of student: ");
    scanf("%d",&stud->ball);
    fprintf(fl,"%-4d",stud->ball);
    stud->mark = 0;
    fprintf(fl,"%-4d\n",stud->mark);
    fclose(fl);
    printf("The student's addition was successfully completed!\n Press Enter for continue...\n");
    //getch();
    //system("cls");
    return(0);
}

    int viewinfo(char *std,list *stud)
    {
        FILE *fl1;
        fl1  = fopen(std, "r");
        char i = 0;
        list temp;
        if (fl1 == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error open file\n");
            return 1;
        }

        fseek(fl1,0,SEEK_END);
        long size = ftell(fl1);
        fseek(fl1,0,SEEK_SET);
        int sizefile = sizeof(list);
        printf("SIZE:%i\n",sizefile);//Просто проверяют сколько памяти занимает тип list
        if (size != 0)
        {
            fread (&temp,size,1,fl1);
            printf("%-10s %-4d %-4d\n",temp.sur, temp.ball, temp.mark); 
        }else printf("\nThe file is empty!\n\n");


        fclose(fl1);
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Открыть файл как бинарный. Хотя в первую очередь зависит от того, *как записан* файл. А об этом у вас ни слова..

Comment: Пишу в файл с помощью scanf()

Comment: Забавно, как вы пишете с помощью функции для чтения... а если имеете в виду `fprintf` - так и читайте, как записали. Вы же явно пишете не все 128 байт строки, да и `int`ы пишете как строки. А читаете?..

Comment: Не совсем понял с 'int' ами

Comment: Вы их, вероятно, записывали как `"%d"` - т.е. строкой? А `fread`/`fwrite` работает с их бинарным представлением, как они хранятся в памяти.

Comment: Тогда как правильно нужно писать?